# animationend firing on css but not on javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I had some trouble with `animationend` which I did not understand. I still don't understand what is going on (maybe I will add more about what I actually seen later), but I went to CodePen and borrowed an example that does exactly the same animation in pure CSS and in JavaScript only with `animate`.

My modified example is here: https://codepen.io/lborgman/pen/QWwjwrE

The interesting part of the code is this:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js li');
var animations = [];

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
  var animation = elements[i].animate([
    { transform: 'rotate(0deg)', offset: 0 },
    { transform: 'rotate(-12deg)', offset: .08 },
    { transform: 'rotate(270deg)', offset: .3 },
    { transform: 'rotate(-40deg)', offset: .55 },
    { transform: 'rotate(70deg)', offset: .8 },
    { transform: 'rotate(-13deg)', offset: .92 },
    { transform: 'rotate(0deg)', offset: 1 }
  ], {
    duration: 3000,
    // iterations: Infinity,
    easing: 'linear',
    delay: 0
  });
```

The animation works, but I do not get the `animationend` event. (I get this event in the CSS version.)

What is wrong here?

Comment: read some documentation for `.animate` ... you'll want to use the [finished Promise property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/finished)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I have never seen that property. So it is by design that `animationend` does not work? Quite a bit unexpected. (And it does not seem consistent. Sometimes I get the event, but not in the CodePen.)

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately his property is not available in Chrome. So I can not use it.

Comment: that's the problem with using experimental technologies ... limited support in browsers - if you read more documentation, you'll see there's an [onfinish event handler property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/onfinish) that is supported in lesser browsers

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, But actually I think I am more interested in the bugs I have seen in this case. I am just checking to see I did not misunderstand how it is supposed to work right now.

Comment: what bugs? is it *supposed* to fire `animationend` event? what makes you think it should?

Comment: @JaromandaX Hm, I am not quite sure at the moment, but I believe I have seen it fired. Maybe I did not remove all the old CSS code? I have to check. What makes you think the event should not fire?

Comment: oh, but that makes no difference anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX Ha, ha. Yes, I placed that wrong. But there is no .animate on the UL elements. I still do not get the event on the js part. But now I get the event on the UL elements too in the css part.

Comment: OK, so, what makes you think animationstart and animationend *should* fire on those elements. Nothing in the documentation for `.animate` suggests that it should

Comment: @JaromandaX Because I know of no other way to detect when the animation has finished. So it seems reasonable to assume that the same event should be used. But that is what I am trying to find out here.

Comment: `.animate` returns an object which you can use the `onfinished` property to handle when an animation ends - I thought I already posted when you told me your browser  doesn't support the `finished` Promise ... so that is how you detect when animation ends when using `.animate`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, yes, I just saw it: http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2015/07/animations-part-2/ That answers my question.

Comment: *I just saw it* ... I mentioned it 35 minutes ago ... *you'll see there's an onfinish event handler property*

Comment: @JaromandaX No idea why I missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a similar result using `.onfinish` property of the object returned by `.animate`

like so:

```js
const liEnds = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (let li of liEnds) {
  li.addEventListener("animationend", function (){
    this.style.background = "green";
  });
  li.addEventListener("animationstart", function (){
    this.style.background = "#55f";
  });

}

const ulEnds = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
for (let ul of ulEnds) {
  ul.addEventListener("animationend", function (){
    this.style.background = "#ff0";
  });
  ul.addEventListener("animationstart", function (){
    this.style.background = "#f00";
  });
}



const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js li');
const animations = [];
elements.forEach(element => {
  var animation = element.animate([{
      transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
      offset: 0
    },
    {
      transform: 'rotate(-12deg)',
      offset: .08
    },
    {
      transform: 'rotate(270deg)',
      offset: .3
    },
    {
      transform: 'rotate(-40deg)',
      offset: .55
    },
    {
      transform: 'rotate(70deg)',
      offset: .8
    },
    {
      transform: 'rotate(-13deg)',
      offset: .92
    },
    {
      transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
      offset: 1
    }
  ], {
    duration: 3000,
    // iterations: Infinity,
    easing: 'linear',
    delay: 0
  });
  animation.onfinish = function() {
    element.style.background = 'green';
    element.parentElement.style.background = "#ff0";
  };
  element.style.background = "#55f";
  element.parentElement.style.background = "#f00";
  animations.push(animation);
});
document.querySelector('.css').classList.add('activated');
document.querySelector('.js').classList.add('activated');
```

```css
body {
  background: #135569;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6rem;
}

li {
  background: #dedfee;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.css li {
  background: #d05f5e;
  animation: translation 3s 0s 1 linear;
}

@keyframes translation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  8% {
    transform: rotate(-12deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(270deg)
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotate(-40deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(70deg)
  }
  92% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

ul {
  background-color: #e70;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fafbff;
  background: #fafbff20;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul class="js">
  <li>js</li>
  <li>js</li>
</ul>
<ul class="css">
  <li>css</li>
  <li>css</li>
</ul>
```